# Should I reinitialize critical sections in Windows?

Tags: windows, critical-section

I use critical sections a lot in Windows programming.
As far as I know, a certain "counter" increases every a critical section is being entered and/or leaved.

I don't need this kind of counter, however I wonder if it's safe to initialize a critical section once for my entire application and then leave it initialized until my program exits.

Should I reinitialize (Delete and Initialize) critical sections every time some tasks have been completed and start over or is it safe to "reuse" already initialized critical sections?

Is there a limit on how often a critical section can be entered/leaved?

Also: 
With every enter/leave - will there be more and more memory consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need initialize critical sections only once. you not need reinitialize it. no any limitation how many time and threads will be enter/leave CS. and of course no more memory will be used after you initialize critical section